# Android broadcast intent null

Tags: android, broadcast, intentfilter

```
      val br = MyReceiver()
            var filter = IntentFilter().apply { addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
            }
    var intent2 = Intent(requireActivity(), MyReceiver::class.java)
            intent2.putExtra("Test", "value")

requireActivity().registerReceiver(br,filter)
requireActivity().sendBroadcast(intent2)




 override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        var st = intent.getStringExtra("Test")
           Log.d("boradtest", st) // in normal operation
 
  
        if (intent.action.equals(ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            var toast = Toast.makeText(context, st, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.show()
        }

    }
}
```

if (intent.action.equals(ACTION_SCREEN_ON))

The st value will be null at this point.

Please tell me what to do to receive the data normally

Comment: You never set action on `intent2` . use `intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)`

Comment: permission denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.screen_on

I get an error like this

looking for permission
 When I put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> in FannyMast, an error appears as it is. Can you help me once more?

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is automatically triggered, when screen of your device has turrned on. You no need additional send it. But, if you still want to send it manually, use `var intent2 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)`

Comment: Even if I do that I get the same error as above....

Comment: That error is very cleair and not related with your main question - you didn't gain permissions for sending sms. How you can do it, you can read e.g. [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidPermissions/article.html)